# How can I strip .git files from submodules if submodules may have common parent directory?

Tags: git

I have a collection of submodules and a build script that is handed down to me.

The script wants to remove the `.git` subdirectory from each submodule. My collection of submodules includes two submodules that are supposed to be created in subdirectories of a common directory:

Some details expurgated, this represents what is in `.gitmodules` (along with currently five or so additional modules that are not located under `parent`:

```
[submodule "parent/expat"]
        path = parent/expat
        url = /path/to/expat.git
[submodule "parent/build"]
        path = parent/build
        url = /path/to/External.git
```

The script currently contains this line to remove the .git files:

```
git submodule foreach --quiet --recursive rm -rf .git
```

This gets an error:

```
error: pathspec 'parent/build/' did not match any file(s) known to git.
Did you forget to 'git add'?
```

This script works fine with other folk's collections of submodules already, so any fix I submit will be looked at closely. The only fix I have come up would hypothetically not cover cases that the current command covers.

If I delete the `--recursive` option from the `foreach` command, then in my case all the unwanted `.git` directories are removed.

Either one of these could be the answer:

- Can I defend my change? Of course if my colleagues turn out to unexpectedly be using nested submodules I may not be able to.
- Can I do something equivalent and EQUALLY SIMPLE that will remove the `.git` directories? Presumably the past authors knew about things like `find . -name .git -exec rm -rf {};` and decided to use `submodule foreach --recursive` knowingly.

I am also looking to the future, when I will convert to git a more complex project. It would share the same External.git submodule, the expat module, and several more modules that will be siblings of the expat module, along with of course more submodules which don't go under `parent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`submodule foreach --recursive` probably starts by executing the command (removing the `.git`) and then try to find sub-submodules... except it no longer operates in a submodule git repo (since its .git just got erased).

The `find . -name .git -exec rm -rf {};` is a <del>safer approach</del>.
The [OP cardiff space man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/606961/cardiff-space-man) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33862793/how-can-i-strip-git-files-from-submodules-if-submodules-may-have-common-parent/33864324#comment55532798_33864324):

> `find . -name .git -exec rm -rf {};` also fails because one of the `.git`'s is a directory which has disappeared between when `find` notices it is a directory and when `find` wants to visit its children.
>   So **it has to be a `find|xargs` pipeline**.

Comment: Your comment is such a plausible explanation that I just did an experiment to double check my assumptions. My assumption was that my predecessors had used this path in the script successfully (it also has a more-frequently-used subversion option). My assumption was wrong. The command `git submodule foreach --recursive rm -rf .git` doesn't look like it is viable under any circumstances. That means the premise of my question is invalid. I'll be deleting it in an hour or so. A compromise between taking it down instantly and giving you and the upvoter a chance to see this comment.

Comment: I defer to your judgement

Comment: `find . -name .git -exec rm -rf {};` also fails because one of the .git's is a directory which has disappeared between when `find` notices it is a directory and when `find` wants to visit its children. So it has to be a `find|xargs` pipeline

Comment: @cardiffspaceman OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.